# Evaluate formula after replacing dependent cells using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am able to both read and write cell values using Apache POI. When reading, I evaluate first so that I get the correct values. My use case requires that I read a sheet, replace a few values in the sheet, then read another portion of the sheet that contains cells that depend on the cells I just replaced.

Example.

`A1` contains a formula: `=B1+C1`. `B1` contains `2` and `C1` contains `3`. When I evaluate `A1` I correctly get `5`. Now, if I replace, with POI api, `C1` with `10`, I would expect that when I read `A1` again I would see `12`. I don't... `A1` now evaluates to `null`.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your question is answered in [Apache POI documentation (under 'Recalculation of Formulas')](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)

Basically it suggests something like:

```
Workbook wb = ...
wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

Comment: It looks like my issue was not that at all. When replacing the cells, I was using `sheet.creatRow(r)` versus `sheet.getRow(r)`.